# How to get a formarray value via template?

Tags: html, forms, angular

In my ionic page i have a reactive form which contains 1 formarrays inside and i need to send the formarray value via json. How can i access only the form array value? The form.value output with json pipe is this

```
      "itemRows": [
      {
     "nervosControl": "",
     "ladoNervoControl": "",
     "latenciaControl": "",
     "amplitudeDistalControl": "",
     "amplitudeProxControl": "",
     "velocidadeControl": "",
     "ondaFControl": ""
      }
      ]
```

I cant have that "itemRows" which is the name of the formarray, i need its content. Im sending to the database with HTTP post wih this method

```
     postNeuromotora(params){
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
      return this.http.post(`${this.api}neuromotora/`,params,{
      headers: headers
      }).map(
       (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
       );

            }
```

Any idea? i tried form.controls.ItemRows.controls and ItemRows.value but it wont let me

Comment: `form.controls.itemRows.value` should do the trick, make sure you don't have other errors preventing that from working

Comment: U're right it was a typo ¬_¬